# Passing a variable from <script> to HTML code?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to pass a variable declared between `<script>` TAGs to the URL in a iframe TAG, like this:

```
<script>
   var1 = 1;
</script>

<iframe src="http://link_to_site?param=var1>
```

But this does not work. Is it possible to do it and how should i do ?

Thanks

Comment: HTML doesn't work like that.  What you would do is identify the target HTML element in your JavaScript code and modify its `src` attribute in that code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but could you give a short example of it because i'm not sure to understand...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you would need a way to identify the target element in your JavaScript code.  For example, give the element an `id` attribute:

```
<iframe id="myIframe" />
```

(There are certainly other ways to identify an element.  Fairly complex queries can be constructed to identify specific elements throughout the DOM.  But an `id` is a particularly straightforward approach at least for this example.)

Then in your JavaScript code you'd get a reference to that element and set its `src` property:

```
var var1 = 1;
document.getElementById('myIframe').src = 'http://link_to_site?param=' + var1;
```

One thing to note is that this code would need to execute *after* that element exists on the page.  If it runs above that element on the page then that element won't yet exist and `getElementById()` would return nothing.

"After" could mean that it runs immediately but exists "lower" on the page than the element.  Or it could mean that the code is placed anywhere on the page but doesn't actually execute until a later time, such as in an event handler.

Comment: Thanks you for this answer ! A last question though, is it possible to retrieve the value of a specific Element with its "id" ?

Comment: @mric750: Of course.  You can pretty much do anything to examine or manipulate the HTML elements from JavaScript.  If the element has a `value` property (such as an `input` element) then you'd just read `.value` on the element reference.

Comment: BTW- this doesn't actually work 100%. See this article: http://www.aaronpeters.nl/blog/iframe-loading-techniques-performance

Answer (score 1):

***FYI- Sorry, but the accepted answer doesn't actually work. Read below. ***

I suggest that you use the jQuery JS library to assist in your task. It normalizes the JS environment so you don't have to worry about what browser your user is using.

It also makes it easier to do some simple tasks like getting specific elements etc.

Here is code that shows how to dynamically create an iFrame AFTER the page has finished loading. This is important because JS runs synchronously: in other words, if you write JS for a specific element, but that element doesn't yet exist on the page, the JS will fail.

By wrapping your code in:

```
$(document).ready(function(){})
```

you ensure that the page will finishing loading BEFORE your JS executes.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>

<body>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var1 = 1;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var theiFrame = '<iframe src="http://link_to_site?param=' + var1 + '">';
        $('body').append(theiFrame);    
    })
</script>
```

iFrames are a little weird in that they mess with the "onload" event of the document. That's another reason to dynamically add your iFrame to the DOM instead of adding it as an HTML tag. Read this article for more info:

http://www.aaronpeters.nl/blog/iframe-loading-techniques-performance

Comment: Sorry, I thought the code kind of explained itself. I'll add details.

Comment: Everyone who is going to see this question and their answers will have a differently level of knowledge about JavaScript. For some it may be obvious  what happens, for others it may not. You can't know that beforehand. But besides explaining your solution you should also explain the OP's problem: Why doesn't their solution work? If you don't explain things, others will have a harder time to learn.